# Easily insert data into any position of a stream without overwriting?

Tags: c#, memorystream

What's the easiest way to do this with a normal memorystream?  Aside from creating 2 streams.

Comment: Are you asking for functionality akin to `List<T>.Insert()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option is to use a `List<byte>` instead of a `MemoryStream` and call the `InsertRange` method.